# pickling with unicode in Python3

Tags: python, pickle, python-unicode

I am trying to pickle a dictionary of the form {word : {docId : int}}. My code is below:

```
def vocabProcess(documents):
    word_splitter = re.compile(r"\w+", re.VERBOSE)
    stemmer=PorterStemmer()#
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

    wordDict = {}
    for docId in documents:
        processedDoc = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in 
        word_splitter.findall(reuters.raw(docId)) if not w in stop_words]

        for w in processedDoc:
            if w not in wordDict:
                wordDict[w] = {docId : processedDoc.count(w)}
            else:
                wordDict[w][docId] = processedDoc.count(w)
    with open("vocabListings.txt", "wb") as f:
        _pickle.dump(wordDict, f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    documents = reuters.fileids()
    with open("vocabListings.txt", "r") as f:
        vocabulary = _pickle.load(f)
```

When I run this code, I get the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2399: 
character maps to <undefined>
```

Why is this breaking when none of the reuters docs/docids have unicode in them? How do I fix this so that I can still use the _pickle module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use binary mode for both writing *and* reading pickles. Your problem is:

```
with open("vocabListings.txt", "r") as f:
    vocabulary = _pickle.load(f)
```

On Python 3, reading in text mode gives `str` (a text type) not `bytes` (the binary type that `pickle` works with). And it will try to decode the data as if it were text in your locale's encoding; a raw binary stream is not likely to be valid in many encodings, so you'll have an error before `pickle` even sees the data.

On Python 2 on Windows, reading in text mode sometimes works, unless the binary data has a `\r\n` sequence in the data, in which case the data will be corrupted (it will be replaced with a `\n` in the data `pickle` sees).

Either way, use mode `"rb"` to read (just like you used `"wb"` to write), and you'll be fine.